# Please specify product's required option(s) magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, reorder

I am adding product into my cart through productid and qty but when i load into cart it's displaying this message.
Please specify product's required option(s).

```
 <?php 
namespace Racom\Chatbotapi\Model;

use Racom\Chatbotapi\Api\ChatbotapiInterface;

class Chatbotapi implements ChatbotapiInterface
{

    protected $order;
    protected $cart;
    protected $session;
    protected $product;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    /**
     * This fuction performs the reorder operation.
     *
     * @api
     * @param Integer $orderId order Id.
     * @param Integer $customerId customer Id.
     * @return string Successfully reordered.
     */
    public function reOrder($orderId,$customerId) 
    {
        try{
            $productCollection = $this->order->load($orderId);
            //If customer's id is equal then load the order.
            if($customerId == $productCollection->getData('customer_id'))
            {
                $order = $this->order->load($orderId);  //Load an order by $orderId.
                $orderInformation = $order->getData();  //Getting data of a particular order by $orderId.
                $orderAllItems = $order->getAllItems();
                foreach ($orderAllItems as $item)
                {
                    $options = $item->getProductOptions(); 
                    print_r(json_encode($options));         //For getting the options of product.
                    print_r(json_encode($orderInformation)); //For getting information of order
                }
                $param = array();
                //Total quantity of an order
                $param['qty'] = $orderInformation['total_qty_ordered'];
                //product item options
                $param['options'] = $options;
                //for getting product id.
                $productId = $item->getId();
                $product = $this->product->load($productId);
                if ($product)
                {
                    //This is where I am getting message that "Please specify product's required option(s)".
                    $this->cart->addProduct($product,$param);
                    $this->cart->save();
                    return json_encode("Successfully added product into shopping cart.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
               return json_encode("customerId and orderId not match.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            return "Can't add product into cart";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Admin please go into the product and check of you have any custom options added. If custom options are added, the customer might need to checkbox those options on the front-end to continue to checkout.

Comment: Yes I do have custom options.

Comment: Make sure those custom options are being automatically selected, if not that is what is stopping you.

Comment: but when I try to load simple product into cart then its giving me this error. XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/chatbotapi/reorder/000000004/5
Line Number 1, Column 1:{"info_buyRequest":{"uenc":"aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlbnRvL2VsZWN0cm9uaWMuaHRtbA,,

Comment: It means it gives me error on $options = $item->getProductOptions();

Comment: Dhaval Mistry,  I have the same problem, did you solve it?