# Please specify product option(s) when selected this bundled product from admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin

Why this error occurs in **Magento 2** " Please specify product option(s). " I selected this bundled product  from admin panel already anybody can help me out **thank you**

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot?

Comment: this error show "Please specify product option(s)." when i add to cart the bundle product and it didnot add to cart and open the product view page and show thiss error on top @LAW

Comment: can you please check this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188238/please-specify-products-required-options-magento-2

Comment: i checked this already its not work for me please help

Comment: please help me still issue is pending @LAW

Comment: Can you try to create with a bundle product from scratch and add it to cart and share if the issue still exists?

Comment: i did the same thing @LAW